# How to specify the padding length as an argument in Guile's format?

Tags: scheme, guile

Guile's format can pad arguments:

```
(format #f "~5d" 123)  ;; => "  123"
```

But how to read the padding length from the arguments?

```
(format #f "~?d" 5 123)  ;; => "  123"
```

As it is done by Bash's printf:

```
printf "%*d" 5 123  ## => "  123"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the Guile [Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output.html), you can use the `v` parameter.

> **v** - The next function argument as the parameter. v stands for “variable”, a parameter can be calculated at runtime and included in the arguments. Upper case V can be used too.

For example:

```
(format #f "~vd" 5 123)
=> "  123"
```

Comment: I missed the forest for the trees.